# ipsec pki error (plugin-openssl-failed-to-load-openssl-plugin-create-not found and no plugin file available)

Tags: kali-linux, openssl, ipsec, strongswan

Im trying to establish a vpn connection with a self signed certificate between 2 virtual machines in my M1 mac and it seems that its impossible to create the keys and the certificate due to the titles error. ive tried almost anything can anyone drop any ideas? thx a lot
Idomeneas

i updated ipsec(Linux strongSwan U5.9.8/K6.0.0-kali3-arm64 ) openssl (openssl is already the newest version (3.0.7-1).) kali linux 2022.2 arm 64

Comment: uff, does this work on a normal Linux distribution, not one exclusively meant for penetration tests, not regular networking?

Comment: well my professor really insists on doing this on kali despite the fact that apple silicon is really not the best option for virtual machines however I'm gonna try it on ubuntu as my last resort

Comment: ah, M1 has nice x86 virtualization, don't worry too much about it. Whipping up a ubuntu VM should be quick and painless – I think ubuntu itself offers VM images! From your error, this really just seems to be that some swan parts are not properly installed, which boils down to your Linux distro not doing something properly. I could be wrong – but if creating the keys takes 15 minutes on a fresh installation of strongswan on ubuntu, then we can rule out you're the one doing something wrong quickly!

Comment: ill try , thanks a lot <3

Comment: Is the `libstrongswan-standard-plugins` package installed? (It's only recommended for the `libstrongswan` package, so it might not be.)

Comment: @ecdsa omg my friend I hope you live a long and prosperous life, I was trying for like 6 hours str8 <3 whenever u come to Greece I owe u a restaurant and drinks

Comment: :) also note that you might not actually need the _openssl_ plugin (unless you want to generate ECDSA keys or have issues with entropy on the system as the _random_ plugin is a bit more strict and only reads from `/dev/random` for private keys).

Comment: yeah I actually want ecsa

Answer (score 1):

The *openssl* plugin is shipped in the `libstrongswan-standard-plugin` package on Debian-based systems.  Since the `libstrongswan` package only only recommends that package it might not be installed automatically.

Also note that the *openssl* plugin is not strictly necessary for the functionality of the `pki` command. Only certain key types require it (e.g. ECDSA or Ed448).